# Image not showing up in Build Apk in React-native

Tags: android, react-native, apk, expo

I have fetched image URL in my react-native app. The image is showing in locally ( Emulator , Phone) but it is not showing up in build apk.

**Sample Image URL:** https://www.hasbro.com/common/productimages/en_US/FF4E4CAD803A43EB8CF60C88DD60CAB9/cd5a2bbe53486fc24df21f8d5c039960d9f90401.jpg

Using React-native-paper card component : https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/card.html

**Sample code:**

```
<Card style={styles.Item}>
<Card.Content>
<Card.Cover
    source={{ uri: row.imageUrl }}
/>
</Card.Content>
</Card>
```

**Emulator View**

[image]

**Installed APK View**


[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm:

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

is in your android project manifest file.